# Absolutely bizarre compiler behavior - constructor not getting called.

Tags: c++, qt, constructor, declaration

I have a class named [`NitroShare::FileServer`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/nitroshare/nitroshare0.3/view/head:/libnitrosharenet/include/nitrosharenet/fileserver.h) that has two constructor:

```
FileServer(QObject * parent = NULL);
FileServer(const Certificate & certificate, QObject * parent = NULL);
```

The implementation of the first constructor is [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/nitroshare/nitroshare0.3/view/head:/libnitrosharenet/src/server/fileserver.cpp) (line 29):

```
FileServer::FileServer(QObject * parent)
    : QObject(parent), d(new FileServerPrivate(this))
{
    qDebug("Constructor invoked!");
}
```

This class is a member of another class named [`NitroShareClient`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/nitroshare/nitroshare0.3/view/head:/nitroshare-client/src/nitroshareclient.h):

```
NitroShare::FileServer server;
```

So, one would assume that the first constructor above would be called when an instance of the `NitroShareClient` class is created. However, it isn't. And consequently, the program crashes.

Here's where things go from frustrating to truly bizarre: if I replace the constructor declaration in the first line above with:

```
FileServer(QObject * parent = NULL) : d(NULL) { qDebug("Constructor invoked!"); }
```

...the constructor *actually is invoked!* Same signature. Same parameters. Same body. The only difference is the location of the function definition.

Can anyone explain what's going on here? If it helps, I'm using GCC 4.7 on Linux.

Comment: Do you have a call stack for the crash?  Is it possible that `new FileServerPrivate(this)` is throwing an exception?  The crash may be occurring *as* the constructor is called.

Comment: @wilsonmichaelpatrick: The crash occurs long after the `NitroShareClient` constructor finishes. The crash takes place in a later section of code that tries to dereference a pointer contained in `NitroShare::FileServer` (the pointer is uninitialized because the constructor is never called). Also, the compiler doesn't even complain if I comment out the definition of the constructor for `NitroShare::FileServer`, leading me to believe that the compiler isn't even *trying* to use it.

Comment: @Nathan Osman It seems more likely to me that there's a one definition rule violation, with multiple implementations of the constructor - but when it's inlined in the header the one definition rule no longer applies.

Comment: Are you sure the pointer is not `NULL`? Dereferencing a null pointer is UB.

Comment: @MarkB: The `QObject` class only defines a single constructor whose signature is: `QObject(QObject * parent = 0)`. Since `NitroShare::FileServer` inherits directly from `QObject`, doesn't my constructor override the `QObject` one?

Comment: @JesseGood: Are you referring to the part of my question where I inline the constructor? Yes, you are correct - that should and does crash the program. However, that happens after the constructor is called, so it's okay for demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Correcting my earlier comment: The fact that you use `using namespace NitroShare;` instead of including the constructor definition in `namespace NitroShare { ... }` may be the cause for the kind of name clash that Mark B refers to.

Comment: @jogojapan: But how could that cause a name clash? I tried your suggestion (prefixing the constructor with the `NitroShare` namespace) but that didn't make any difference. It would seem like the compiler isn't even looking for the definition of the constructor.

Comment: @NathanOsman I assumed there is another `FileServer` class in the global namespace (or another namespace you are `using` at the same point). In that case the compiler may choose to implement the constructor for the wrong class. Of course that would still leave open the question why the linker doesn't complain about the missing implementation for the `NitroShare::FileServer` constructor. Could there be another file that implements a constructor for a `FileServer` class, which ends up being defined inside the `NitroShare` namespace? Watch out for `using namespace` declarations in included files.

Comment: @jogojapan: There is nothing else in the Qt framework or my project named `FileServer` in any namespace. It's a uniquely-named class.

Comment: I browsed through the code a bit, and [found another FileServer](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/nitroshare/nitroshare0.3/view/head:/libnitroshare/src/file/fileserver.cpp).

Comment: @JesseGood: Wha... how did you find that? I must have done that so long ago I forgot about it. And yes, this is very embarrassing for me. After spending nearly two days on this bug, I was beginning to think I had uncovered some mysterious bug in GCC :) I've removed the "old" `FileServer` and rebuilt the project. Lo and behold: it works. **Thank you.** If you want to post this as an answer below, I will gladly upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credits technically should go to [Mark B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182951/absolutely-bizarre-compiler-behavior-constructor-not-getting-called#comment23134343_16182951) and [jogojapan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182951/absolutely-bizarre-compiler-behavior-constructor-not-getting-called#comment23134843_16182951) for pointing out the problem. The compiler was using the constructor for a different `FileServer` class found [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/nitroshare/nitroshare0.3/view/head:/libnitroshare/src/file/fileserver.cpp) violating the one-definition rule.